# How to disable and enable the visibility of Horizontal panel in GWT?

Tags: gwt, panel

First of all i have to disable the `Horizontal panel`. I tried with the following code and it the panel was disabled.

```
public void hideNavigaton(){
    pagination.removeFromParent();
}
```

But i have to also enable the above panel after disabling it in following method definition:

```
public void showNavigation(){
    // Add definition to enable the visibility.
}
```

If anything is wrong , then what will be write or appropriate method to enable and disable the visibility of Horizontal panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide you call

```
pagination.setVisible(false)
```

and to show

```
pagination.setVisible(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply hide and show the panel, use setVisible() as suggested by Daniel. In this case the panel will appear/disappear, but it will keep its place in the layout.

If you want the panel to completely disappear and give its space to another widget, you have to remove it from parent. Then you can add it back when you need it.

```
public void hideNavigaton(){
    pagination.removeFromParent();
}
public void showNavigation(){
    myParentWidget.add(pagination);
    // Set position of pagination widget if you don't do it through CSS
}
```